# SOLR compatibility of the KNN query parser with function queries

Tags: search, vector, solr, knn, vector-search

I am experimenting with the SOLR vector search feature (running version 0.9.4) and observing inconsistencies when using the KNN query parser alone or within a function query.

I have configured a vector field and indexed my documents.

**a) Basic KNN query**

Running the following simple KNN query works as expected :

```
q={!knn f=vector_field topK=3}[.. vector here ...]
```

I obtain 3 results ranked by decreasing cosine similarity.

**b) Combining KNN with a function query**

Next I would like to combine the knn search with a function query, in order to boost some of the documents.
To keep it simple here I just multiply the vector score with a constant of 1 :

```
q={!func}product(1,$subQuery)&
subQuery={!knn f=vector_field topK=3}[.. vector here ...]
```

I would expect the same results as before.
Instead, I get random documents, all having a score of zero.
This is the explain statement for the first match :

```
0.0 = product(const(1),query(KnnFloatVectorQuery:vector_field[-0.080,...] 3],def=0.0)=0.0) 1.0 = boost
```

If I increase `topK`, at some point I start getting back the results of the original KNN query, with non-zero scores.

I have not found any documentation regarding the compatibility of the KNN parser with function queries.
Has anyone experimented with this?